Add X days to a Datetime Series
I have a Datetime Series that always contains the datetime of yesterday like:
Series: '' [datetime[ns]]
[
    2024-08-29 00:00:00
]

How can I add 2 days to that Datetime Series so that I can add the datetime from 2 days and 3 days ago?
End result should be:
Series: '' [datetime[ns]]
[
    2024-08-29 00:00:00
    2024-08-28 00:00:00
    2024-08-27 00:00:00
]


Can you provide the series example as code instead of a repr?

why would you even need a Series if it's only one date?

Because it's coming from an external source and may contain more days depending on the flags set.

pl.date_range can be used along with pl.Series.dt.offset_by to create the start date.
pl.date_range(dates.dt.offset_by("-2d"), dates, eager=True)

shape: (3,)
Series: 'dates' [date]
[
    2024-08-27
    2024-08-28
    2024-08-29
]

If the series is required in decreasing order, one can subsequently reverse the series using pl.Series.reverse.
pl.date_range(dates.dt.offset_by("-2d"), dates, eager=True).reverse()


What about using date_range:
X = 2
date = series[0] # get date
# create X extra days
out = pl.date_range(date, date+timedelta(days=X), '1d', eager=True)

Output:
shape: (3,)
Series: 'literal' [date]
[
    2024-08-29
    2024-08-30
    2024-08-31
]

